# When drawing polyline using QGIS it starts on outside of cursor and not in centre?

Tags: qgis, osx

When drawing a polyline in QGIS 3 it starts on the outside of the cursor, not in the centre. Same thing when measuring a line. This makes accuracy difficult.

Am I missing something?

I am using OS X (High Sierra).

Comment: I have the same problem since I switched to QGIS 3 on Mac HS months ago. I posted the question but nobody could figured it out and it post was closed by admins. As far as today, I'm still incapable to use QGIS 3 on Mac because it's impossible to draw features having the center of the cursor not matching with the center of the vertex I'm attempting to draw.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a patch but what I did to fix it was to set the default cursor to a different one using this code in the Python console

```
QApplication.instance().setOverrideCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)
```

The only problem is that now even the general pointer has the cross-shaped cursor but at least the center of the cursor correspond to the vertex I'm drawing

Answer (score 1):

I reverted to 2.18 until 3 was more mature. Tried 3.2, problem solved!